# Zoho Catalyst:HTTP Error 401, You do not have privileges to access this project. Please contact the project owner or an administrator of this account

Tags: command-line-interface, serverless

I'm using the Zoho Catalyst CLI to debug my code locally. I have two projects, each in a separate folder with a different Zoho account. I'm the super admin of my current project, however I face an issue saying that I do not have adequate privileges to this project.

I tried running the `catalyst serve` command but I keep getting this error that says that I do not have administrator privileges. Here are the commands I used `catalyst login` , `catalyst init` and finally `catalyst serve`. I'm attaching a screenshot of the issue I faced.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a Zoho account
2. Install Catalyst CLI
3. Use the [catalyst login and init command](https://catalyst.zoho.com/help/cli-command-reference.html)
4. Use the catalyst serve command to debug locally to reproduce the issue

This issue occurs every time during local debugging only.

[Screenshot of the issue faced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UrWr.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you have separate folders for separate projects,let us say you are initialising in this location : ~/catalyst/aliencity ,then the previous folders namely Catalyst or ~(home directory) might have a Catalyst project initialised. Delete all the catalyst related files including a hidden file named .catalystrc and then try the catalyst serve command